# Install linux from and on to the same HDD

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, external-hard-drive

I have a PC with no internal HDD, but I have an external HDD. I want install the Ubuntu on it (on the external HDD) but I could only reboot Ubuntu from that same external HDD (I tried burning the image on a DVD and booting from that but it wouldn't let me). So my question is, can I boot Ubuntu from the external HDD and install the OS on the same HDD?

Comment: this is possible definitely, but the procedure depends on the OS you are using to prepare your HDD. What OS you are going to use for that?

Comment: what is the os installed on the external hdd?

Comment: I wanted to install ubuntu on the external HDD. I figured out the way to boot from a flash drive instead of the external HDD. Now I am installing on to the external HDD, but when I restart the PC with only the HDD connected, it tells me there is no OS to load.